# set different color for navigation bar back button and back button text

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to have different colors for back button text and back button.

If I set the global tint, it changes color for both. Is there a way I could have different color for both?

Comment: What does the back button consist of _other_ than the text? In other words, what is the thing-that-is-not-text in the word "both"?

Comment: @matt, I am not sure if I understand. Consider a brand new nav bar. In that i just entered some text for back button. I just want different colors on back button and it's text. For ex, if it looks like `< Back`, i want red color on "<" and orange on "Back"

Comment: hay i think you can do this easily if there its not any issue . you can set tint color on the specific view controler viewDidLoad method like this : ```self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.red
``` and than another view controller viewdidLoad  ```self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.green```

Answer (score -1):

As i understand you just want to change back button color and back button in different screen different .Not globally So you can do this several way .Here is simplest way.

Just change navigation tint color of its viewDidLoad or viewWillApper method.

ViewController One :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
   self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.green

    }
```

ViewConbtroller Two :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
   self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.red

    }
```